# Onenote vba copy a page like copy/move

Tags: vba, onenote

I would like instruction to copy page like right click on page and move/copy

Comment: Helloi have finally do the stuff with .mergesection.i have always the same page template so i have just to merge

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.